# How Do You Pronounce "Tuesday"?

Tags: pronunciation, diphthongs

My friends have a variety of ways of pronouncing "Tuesday":

- Tooos-day
- Tyu-sday
- Choose-day

Which one is considered correct?

Comment: A guy here at work says _toos-dee_ (and -dee for every other day as well).

Comment: Everyone knows that Solomon Grundy was born on a Mondee, and christened on Tuesdee.

Comment: @Mahnax: So perhaps we should edit three more variations in to OP's text, each ending in *-dee* instead of *-day*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are really only two phonemic variants here:

1. First syllable is /tu:/
2. First syllable is /tju:/

The variation between these two forms is an instance of the widespread idiosyncratic insertion of /j/ before /u:/ in many English dialects. Another common word with this variation is *tune*, which is pronounced both as /tu:n/ and /tju:n/. Generally both variants are accepted as correct, though your dialect will vary in which one it prefers.

The variant pronunciation with "choose-day" is a matter of dialects in which the cluster /tj/ is regularly pronounced as [tʃ] ("ch"). This is another common dialectical feature which is generally accepted as correct in the regions where it occurs. When you have someone who begins "Tuesday" with /tju:/ *and* produces /tj/ as [tʃ], you'll hear them pronounce the word with [tʃu:] as the first syllable.

Comment: It appears that for the days of the week, some people say `/di/` instead of `/deɪ/`. You hear this in the American South, for example, where they rhyme “fundy” (as in fundamentalist) with “Sunday”. Perhaps this is only a phonological effect, but normally `/eɪ/` and `/i/` are distinct phonemes. It might only be with days of the week. I’d have to find other words ending in `/eɪ/` and run it by them to check.

Comment: -1: this is not an "idiosyncratic" "insertion" of /j/ before /u:/; it's a regular retention of historical /ju:/. Might seem pedantic, but this is a point where people may actually be confused about the relative chronology. The pronunciation  /tu:n/ represents an (also regular) [*dropping*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_English_consonant_clusters#Yod-dropping) of /j/.

Answer (score 7):

In Australian English, I hear /tʃuz/ (chooze). In British, /tyuz/. In American dialects, thanks to yod-dropping, you hear /tuz/. In some dialects, you can hear a diphthong /iu/, which sounds similar to /yu/.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your dialect.  [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/tuesday) lists your first two choices, as well as another pronunciation of *day*: **/ˈtuzdeɪ, -di, ˈtyuz-/**  (four possibilities - *tooz-day, tyooz-day, tooz-dee*, and *tyooz-dee*).

"Correct" is relative.  If your dialect pronounced Tuesday *choose-day*, it would be considered correct by those used to the dialect.  The only thing dictionaries are useful for (when you're looking up pronunciations) is to find which is the most popular/preferred.

Note that there are boundaries, though, to correctness - it's not all mush.  For instance, it would be unequivocably incorrect to pronounce Tuesday *Sunday*.

Comment: But in my dialect, we **do** pronounce "Tuesday" as *Sunday*.